# RAM only works in specific slot/order

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard

I have a weird issue. I have two slots on my mobo but the RAM seems to work only in specific order. It will only work if RAM 1 is in slot 1 and RAM 2 is in slot 2, if I switch the position, it doesn't work. Although they are completely the same model. I am also occasionally getting screen freeze/flicker. Does this suggest a defective RAM slot or RAM?

Edit:

I figured out my other RAM is broken (it returns a lot of errors when using memtest+) however when I switch my other working RAM to slot 2 it doesn't work so I figured my slot 2 could be also broken. My question now is: Is it normal that when using only one RAM, it should only work on slot 1 or should it work on either slots?

Edit #2:

Mobo: lga1155 Asrock H61M VS B3

RAM: G.Skill RipJaws X (Dual) 2x2gb ddr3 1333 CL8 (F3 10666CL8D 4GBXM)

(I built this custom PC, not branded/out of the box)

Comment: if possible could u post the screenshot of two slots and ram which you have

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Motherboards can be rather finicky as regarding the placement of RAM sticks.

Probably your RAM sticks are not exactly identical, so the motherboard is only willing
to accept them in that order.

However, there are two problems with your RAM :

1. The [motherboard specs](http://www.asrock.nl/mb/overview.asp?Model=H61M-VS) say DDR3 1600 while you have 1333.
2. The 10666CL8D-4GBXM stick is not in the [H61M-VS Memory Support List](http://www.asrock.nl/mb/memory.asp?Model=H61M-VS).

Not being in the supported list may on the one hand only mean that it wasn't tested by Asrock, but it can also mean tested and found to be incompatible (or even only partially compatible). Judging by your experience, either one can be true, but I would bet on the second one.

I would guess that the RAM you have is not defective, but its compatibility is suspect.
If you found a positioning of the sticks that works, you should be thankful, but be on the lookout for problems.

Personally, I would advice on using memory that is on the supported list.

Comment: You should see what the BIOS (UEFI) says about your RAM when booting with the two sticks in both positions. One false note: the [mobo specs](http://www.asrock.nl/mb/overview.asp?Model=H61M-VS) say DDR3 1600 while you have 1333. Another fairly strong false note: the 10666CL8D-4GBXM is not in the [H61M-VS Memory Support List](http://www.asrock.nl/mb/memory.asp?Model=H61M-VS).

Comment: If it wasn't in the supported memory list, is it possible that my "defective" RAM is not defective at all?

Answer (score 1):

Either slot should work. What mother board do you have? The manual should tell you if it did matter. If it does not, then it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, specific order shouldn't matter as far as I know (AFAIK).

I've 2 x 2GB DDR3 RAM and I've tried swapping the RAM b/w the slots and it works perfectly. My motherboard is Intel DH61WW with latest BIOS firmware.

I'd suggest you to clean RAM with an eraser, just rub the eraser on those small metallic chips on the RAM and clean RAM slots by blowing air with "A can of compressed air". Also, try inserting RAM on some other compatible motherboard, may be your friends could help, and see if they work.

If nothing else works then there might be some problem in your RAM or RAM slots.

Answer (score 0):

if you can try setting the timing lower in bios/efi, and/or go a little higher on dram voltage (like 1.65v if the memory is 1.6v)